# Click link to related slider item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I did a basic slider using jQuery and only margin-left, I can not use plugins. 
Also do not have access to the HTML, the next and previous buttons works well for transition of sliders. But now I need to operate the links for each slider when you click the link of each slider has to make the transition to their specific slider. but I have no idea how to do this.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <button class="previous">previous</button>
    <div class="item item1">slider 1</div>
    <div class="item item2">slider 2</div>
    <div class="item item3">slider 3</div>
    <div class="item item4">slider 4</div>
    <button class="next">next</button>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="slider1">slider1</a></li>
        <li><a href="slider2">slider2</a></li>
        <li><a href="slider3">slider3</a></li>
        <li><a href="slider4">slider4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jquery

```
var currentSlider = 0;

$('.next').click(function(e) {
    if (currentSlider != 1) {
        $('.item').each(function(index, value) {
            var currLeft = parseInt($(value).css('margin-left'));
            var newLeft = currLeft - ($(window).innerWidth());
            $(value).css('margin-left', newLeft + 'px');
        });
        currentSlider += 1;
    };
});

$('.previous').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (currentSlider != -2) {
        $('.item').each(function(index, value) {
            var currLeft = parseInt($(value).css('margin-left'));
            var newLeft = currLeft + ($(window).innerWidth());
            $(value).css('margin-left', newLeft + 'px');

        });

        currentSlider -= 1;
    };
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3vv06805/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry got your point now.You can try this one

```js
jQuery("li a").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var id = jQuery(this).attr("href");
var intid = parseInt(id.substr(id.length - 1));
    alert(jQuery("div.item").length);
jQuery(".item"+id.substr(id.length - 1)).css("margin-left","0px");
var k = 1;
for(i = intid-1;i>0; i--)
{
    jQuery(".item"+i).css("margin-left","-" +543*k+"px");
    k++;
}
var j = 1;
for(i = intid+1;i<=jQuery("div.item").length; i++)
{
    jQuery(".item"+i).css("margin-left", 543*j+"px");
    j++;
}
});
```

Comment: I would complete the transition to arrive at specific slider that was clicked. see the link jsfiddle. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change your html to:

```
<div class="container">
    <button class="previous">previous</button>
    <div class="item item1">slider 1</div>
    <div class="item item2">slider 2</div>
    <div class="item item3">slider 3</div>
    <div class="item item4">slider 4</div>
    <button class="next">next</button>

    <ul id="foo">
        <li><a href="slider1" data-index="-2">slider1</a></li>
        <li><a href="slider2" data-index="-1">slider2</a></li>
        <li><a href="slider3" data-index="0">slider3</a></li>
        <li><a href="slider4" data-index="1">slider4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Change your Javascript to:

```
var currentSlider = 0;

$('.next').click(function(e) {
    if (currentSlider != 1) {
        $('.item').each(function(index, value) {
            var currLeft = parseInt($(value).css('margin-left'));
            var newLeft = currLeft - ($(window).innerWidth());
            $(value).css('margin-left', newLeft + 'px');
        });
        currentSlider += 1;
    };
});

$('.previous').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (currentSlider != -2) {
        $('.item').each(function(index, value) {
            var currLeft = parseInt($(value).css('margin-left'));
            var newLeft = currLeft + ($(window).innerWidth());
            $(value).css('margin-left', newLeft + 'px');

        });

        currentSlider -= 1;
    };
});

function bar(clickedIndex, depth) {
    if (currentSlider < clickedIndex) {
        $(".next").click();
    } else if (currentSlider > clickedIndex) {
        $(".previous").click();
    } else {
        return;
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        bar(clickedIndex, depth + 1);
    }, 2005);
}

$("#foo > li > a").click(function(e) {
    bar($(this).data("index"), 0);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: very good, thank you. you know because it has a conflict when you click quickly?  http://jsfiddle.net/3vv06805/4/
thanks